# Command line bluetooth discovery as in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi, command-line, bluetooth

I'm trying to experiment with Bluetooth discovery from the command line.

I have tried:

- `btdiscovery` from https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools ( via https://superuser.com/questions/1604313/command-line-check-if-a-certain-bluetooth-device-is-discoverable )
- The C code from https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4j.html (via [Unable to connect to Bluetooth Device using Window's Bluetooth API in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908566/unable-to-connect-to-bluetooth-device-using-windows-bluetooth-api-in-c))

Both of these, have the same problem: that when I run Bluetooth "discovery", they report one or two devices maximum, and then they exit.

However, if in Windows 10, I go to: Windows Settings/Devices/Add Bluetooth or other device/Bluetooth, so I get "Add a device" window:

[image: add a device]

... I get a while bunch of devices that are continuously updated (and some disappear, then reappear again)

Does anyone know of a ready (C/C++) example that would reproduce the same results I get in this "Add a device" window, but in the command line/terminal?

Short of that - could anyone give me any pointers on what APIs I'd need to use, in order to replicate the same Bluetooth discovery results from this "Add a device" window in a command line application? (presumably, that would be a continuous Bluetooth discovery process, that would be interrupted by Ctrl-C or similar in the terminal)

Comment: [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth).

Comment: There are 2 ways to do what you need: 1. Use legacy Bluetooth WinAPI functions (Bluetooth sockets). Set longer discovering timeout. Then restart discovering after one completed. You have to use some found devicec cache to check if the device is still available (the same as Add Device dialog and WinRT API do). 2 Use WinRT DeviceWatcher. Please note that in any case you will always get paired devices in the found list even thay are not available.

Comment: for get list of remote bth - [`IOCTL_BTH_GET_DEVICE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthioctl/ni-bthioctl-ioctl_bth_get_device_info). for start new inquire no documented ioctls, but internal system use `BTH_CTL(BTH_IOCTL_BASE+0x400)` with 6 bytes input {LAP_GIAC_VALUE,5,0} and no output

Comment: @RbMm How did you find that value 0x400 and the necessary parameters? What other undocumented functionality is available? Have any links?

Comment: @ChadKennedy in windows bth ioctls handled by *bthport.sys* driver in function *BthHandleControlDispatch* the BTH_CTL(BTH_IOCTL_BASE+0x400)  - `BthValidateInquiryIrp` and than `HCI_HandleInquire` called. i have no any links. i research this myself, when was need implement some bth functional in windows (partial [here](https://github.com/rbmm/BTH) )